# Why SLERP does not interpolate on a geodesic?

Tags: python-3.x, interpolation, orientation, quaternions

not sure if I should do it in Math SE or here so please let me know.

I tried to implement a SLERP algorithm that shows where a point on a unit sphere is moved to given the amount of time lapsed, but I found out the results does not follow the shortest path as I expect SLERP to help me do so. I guess there is something wrong when I tried to use the quaternions' axes to represent the location of the points?

Here's my codes:

```
from pyquaternion import Quaternion as pyQ
import math

ts = (np.linspace(0, 10, 11))/10

def rotate_upon_t(time, start, end):

    for t in time:    
        result = start*(((start)**(-1)) * end)**t
        print(result.axis)

rotate_upon_t(ts, q0, q1)
```

Test case:

```
q0 = pyQ(axis = [0.5*math.sqrt(2), 0, -0.5*math.sqrt(2)], degrees = 180)
q1 = pyQ(axis = [0.5, 0.5, -0.5*math.sqrt(2)], degrees = 180)
```

The results over 10 time steps (ith row gives the location when time `t = i`) are

```
[ 0.70710678  0.         -0.70710678]
[ 0.69515821  0.05256703 -0.71693219]
[ 0.68112236  0.10497623 -0.72460494]
[ 0.66504138  0.15707022 -0.73010199]
[ 0.64696353  0.20869259 -0.73340684]
[ 0.62694312  0.25968834 -0.73450956]
[ 0.60504025  0.30990436 -0.73340684]
[ 0.58132068  0.35918985 -0.73010199]
[ 0.55585564  0.40739684 -0.72460494]
[ 0.52872159  0.45438058 -0.71693219]
[ 0.5         0.5        -0.70710678]
```

I would expect the last column (z-coordinate) of the point to be constant `(-0.5*math.sqrt(2))` because this value is also the z-coordinates of the starting and ending points (`q0.axis` and `q1.axis`). Is my expectation wrong in any way?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to interpolate two 3D vectors, not two quaternions.

Lets say that you want to generate the geodesic G from V1 to V2 using SLERP where V1 and V2 are unit 3D vectors. First I would embed V1 and V2 as pure quaternions Q1, Q2. The quaternion Q rotating from Q1 to Q2 would be:

Q = normalize(Q2 + Q1) * Q1

The interpolation Q(t) would be

Q(t) = Q^t

or equivalently:

Q(t) = exp(t * log(Q))

where t is a scalar between 0 and 1.

Finally the geodesic G(t) would be:

G(t) = Q(t) * Q1 * conjugate(Q(t))

NOTE: the product * is the quaternion product.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I forgot the aircraft flight path may not be along the same altitude even both ends are. It's do-able to prove flying a plane in a "curved" path (e.g. from Tokyo to New York) saves fuel compared to going "straight", but realizing this fact would be enough for me to know this question is stupid enough.